# How can I select all elements without a given class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Given the following:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li class="active">Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

How can I select all but Item 2, AKA something like:

```
$("ul#list li!active")
```

Comment: `$("ul#list").not(".active")` or `$("ul#list:not(.active)")`

Answer (score 484, accepted):

You can use the [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method or [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

Code based on your example:

```
$("ul#list li").not(".active") // not method
$("ul#list li:not(.active)")   // not selector
```

Comment: If want to check two class use as `.not(".completed, .current")`

Comment: in 2019 vanillaJs: document.querySelectorAll('.foo-class:not(.bar-class):not(.foobar-class'))

Answer (score 43):

What about `$("ul#list li:not(.active)")`?

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 21):

You could use this to pick all **`li`** elements without class:

```
$('ul#list li:not([class])')
```

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the jQuery API documentation:
[not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [not equal selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!$(row).hasClass("changed")) {
    // do your stuff
}
```