# jQuery: How to find elements *without* a certain class

Tags: jquery-selectors

Why does this fail...

```
$( 'div.contactAperson input' ).not( 'input.hadFocus' ).focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', '' );
});
```

...it's meant to sniff out input's that have *not* got the class .hadFocus and then when one of that subset receives focus it should zap the value to null.

Right now, input values are always getting zapped -- the test .not( 'input.hadFocus' ) is failing to stop execution.

Btw, preceding the above code is the following code, which is working fine:

```
$( 'div.contactAperson input' ).focus(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( 'hadFocus' );
});
```

Thanks for any cleverness - cheers, -Alan

Comment: Duplicate of: [How can I select all elements without a given class in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448051)

Answer (score 5):

You need the handler to run based on the current state of the element - 
not the state when it was bound. You probably need to use a [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) binding.

Try something like this:

```
$('div.contactAperson input:not(.hadFocus)').live('focus', function() {
    $(this).attr('value', '' );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, sound like that'll be it. Now just gotta find the project this related to. Cheers, -Alan

Answer (score 4):

```
$( 'div.contactAperson > :input' ).not( ':input.hadFocus' ).focus(function() {
    $(this).attr('value', '' );
});
```

good luck

Comment: Tks, dunno why but this version never clears the value. But tks for the code suggestion, I'll keep scratching away at it...