# With JQuery, how do I select all elements with no class

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery get all divs which do not have class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute)

I need to select all elements that have no class defined. How do I do that with JQuery?

Comment: `:)` possible duplicate of [jQuery get all divs which do not have class attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962247/jquery-get-all-divs-which-do-not-have-class-attribute) **or** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715330/jquery-how-to-find-elements-without-a-class-set **or**

Comment: @GabrielSantos: It is for a weird hack I am working on where in order for it to work, I need to take out items with no class defined on them.

Comment: @ :)  The first you mention is kind of similar but has a different focus while the second one does not seem directly related to my question. Anyway, if anyone wants to close this question, be my guest...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(':not([class])')
```

However, note this will also select `html, body, head` if they don't have a class.

Comment: Should not be `$('*:not([class])')`?

Comment: Or `$('body :not([class])')` is one way to just get elements within the body rather than also selecting `html`, `body`, `head`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This query will select all elements and then filter those that do not have the class attribute: `$('*').not('[class]')`

Comment: No problem, mVChr's query is cleaner though.