# Trying to remove html elements from a selector without modifying the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm attempting to save the html contained within DIV id: `#canvas`. Removing all elements with classes: `.show-hide-config` and `.ez-control` before I send it through ajax to the server.
Here's what I have so far but it's far from working.

```
$(".ez-save-page").click(function(){
    var canvas_html = $("#canvas").html();
    canvas_html = $(canvas_html).find(".show-hide-config, .ez-control").remove();
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "./save_page/",
        data: {"save_html": JSON.stringify(canvas_html)},
        success: function(save_result){
            console.log(save_result);
        }
    });
});
```

Example html:

```
<div id="el-1387177861244" class="ui-draggable">
    <button class="show-hide-config">×</button>
    <div class="ez-control">
        <span>Container</span>
        <div class="config_options">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="close">×</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Some content I want to keep including the wrapping div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to be sent:

```
<div id="el-1387177861244" class="ui-draggable">
    <div>
        <p>Some content I want to keep including the wrapping div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The actual html is far mnore complex and could have any number of elements inside but if I can remove 2 classes from a selector without modifying the DOM it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please see this earlier question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448051/how-can-i-select-all-elements-without-a-given-class-in-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the contents of `#canvas`, manipulate them the way you want and grab the resulting HTML. Revised code:

```
var canvas_html = $("#canvas")
    .children()                             // grab .children
    .clone()                                // and .clone
    .find(".show-hide-config, .ez-control") // .find unwanted elements
    .remove()                               // .remove them
    .end()                                  // undo the last .find operation
    .html();                                // grab .html contents
console.log($.trim(canvas_html));
// <div>
//     <p>Some content I want to keep including the wrapping div</p>
// </div>
```

Comment: Jeez louise! You are of course completely correct, I'll mark it so asap. Thanks you.

Comment: Excellent one liner, thanks for the continued improvements, description and speed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#canvas").find(".show-hide-config, .ez-control").remove();
```

instead of

```
canvas_html = $(canvas_html).find(".show-hide-config, .ez-control").remove();
```