# How to get anchor tags without a speciic css class using jquery?

Tags: jquery, dom, filter

I am reading Jquery cook book. i have learn how to filter DOM elements with a specified class. now i want to do opposite from it means now i want to get elements which does not have that specified class.

**My HTML Code is:**

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="external">link</a> 
    <a href="#" class="external">link</a> 
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#" class="external">link</a> 
    <a href="#" class="external">link</a>
</li>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#">link</a> 
    <a href="#">link</a> 
    <a href="#">link</a> 
    <a href="#">link</a></li>
```

**Jquery Code is:**

```
jQuery(function () {
jQuery('a').filter('.external').text('hello testing');
});
```

using the above code i am able to get all anchor tags with the "**external**" class. now i want to get all the anchor tags which **external** class. please help me how can i do it..

Comment: _now i want to get all the anchor tags which external class._ its bit confusing.

Comment: May be it's the time, you should learn how to search too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448051/how-can-i-select-all-elements-without-a-given-class-in-jquery

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991576/select-elements-without-any-class

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614120/not-class-selector-in-jquery

Comment: @KamranAhmed sorry to say.. no one brilliant from birth.. like you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`.not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/) instead of `.filter()`:

```
jQuery('a').not('.external').text('hello testing');
```

Or you can use the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
jQuery('a:not(.external)').text('hello');
```

Note that you can get the same results as your original `.filter()` code without using `.filter()`:

```
jQuery('a.external').text('hello testing');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way too

```
$(function(){
    jQuery('.external').text('hello testing');
    jQuery('a').not('.external').text('hello not testing');
});
```

Comment: didn't get the question first realize after

Answer (score 0):

You can daisy-chain the `not` method to achieve that:

`$('a').text('hello').not('.external').text('goodbye');`

This sets the innerText of all the `a` tags to hello and then selects all the non-`.external` tags and sets them to 'goodbye'.