# Selecting <p> elements that DO NOT contain <span class="foo"> (the end goal of having selective toggle) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a `$(selector)` with certain paragraph elements that do not contain a specific class of span elements, for example: in the following sample text,

```
/* HTML */
<button id="buttonFoo">ButtonFoo</button>
<p> 
    Lorem ipsum...
    <span class="foo">FOO</span>
    Excepteur sint...
</p>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum...
    <span class="foo">FOO</span>
    Duis aute...
    <span class="bar">BAR</span>
    Excepteur sint...
</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum...
    <span class="foo">FOO</span>
    Duis aute...
    <span class="bar">BAR</span>
    Excepteur sint...
</p>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum...
    <span class="foo">FOO</span>
    Excepteur sint...
</p>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum...
    <span class="thing">THING</span>
    Excepteur sint...
</p>

<p>
    Lorem ipsum...
    <span class="thing">THING</span>
    Excepteur sint...
</p>
```

By clicking on the button with id buttonFoo, I want to be able to toggle the paragraph elements that do not contain a span with the class="foo".

I have tried

```
/* JS/jQuery */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonFoo").click(function(){
        $(':not(:contains('+ <span class="foo" +'))').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

This may be a pretty trivial question with a trivial answer, but I am new to programming so input is very appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: where's the span class foo???

Comment: @BhojendraNepal - the first 4 paragraphs contain a `<span class="foo">`  The last 2 contain a `<span class="thing">`

Comment: It was just updated after comments..

Comment: Edited to make it easier to read :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select all elements without a given class in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448051/how-can-i-select-all-elements-without-a-given-class-in-jquery)

Comment: ya, sorry. My first draft was difficult to read. Thanks for pointing that out @BhojendraNepal

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for:

```
$('#buttonFoo').on('click', function(){
    // selects all <p> elements that are not containing
    // any elements that have an element of class="foo"
    // as a descendant:
    $('p:not(:has(.foo))')
        // and then toggles their visibility:
        .toggle();
});
```

```js
$('span.foo').closest('p').addClass('fooHighlight');
$('#buttonFoo').on('click', function() {
  $('p:not(:has(.foo))').toggle();
});
```

```css
.fooHighlight {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonFoo">ButtonFoo</button>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span class="foo">FOO</span> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <span class="foo">FOO</span> Duis
  aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span class="bar>BAR</span> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. <span class="
  foo ">FOO</span> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span class="bar>BAR</span>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
  laborum.
</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span class="foo">FOO</span> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span class="thing">THING</span> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. <span class="thing">THING</span> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

But as none of your posted `<p>` elements seem to contain any `<span>` elements of `class="foo"`, so I'm possibly mis-reading your question.

References:

- [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).
- [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: I couldn't see the element with class foo, did you?

Comment: No, hence the update to the question; but my reading of the question suggests that's what the OP is *trying* to do, albeit with non-representative mark-up (which doesn't make it any easier to try and help).

Comment: they are far to right in html block, so you have to scroll a bit, did not think of that inconvenience when i drafted question, Sorry!

Comment: David Thomas, you are a knight and a scholar. May your springs be long and your winter short! Your response worked

Comment: I'm glad to have been of some help!

Comment: Yes, you must be provided more +1.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [has-selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector) with [not](http://api.jquery.com/not):

```
$('#buttonFoo').on('click', function(){
    $('p').not(:has(.foo)).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#buttonFoo").click(function(){
      $('p').each(function(){
         if($(this).find('span.foo').length == 0) 
            $(this).toggle(); 
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#buttonFoo").click(function(){
       $('p:not(:has("span.foo"))').toggle();
   });
});
```