# How To Ask Does Not Has Class With jQuery Correctly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please forgive my ignorance as I am just starting to learn jQuery.  I am trying to ask iQuery to search my page for images that do not have the Bootstrap class of img-responsive on an image tag.  If the tag has been found then I'd like jQuery to add the class.

This is what I wrote;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ( $("img").hasClass("img-responsive")) {  
        return; }
            else 
            {  $("img").addClass("img-responsive");
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Don

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select all elements without a given class in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448051/how-can-i-select-all-elements-without-a-given-class-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find all images except with the class img-responsive, and add img-responsive to them.

```
$("img:not(.img-responsive)").addClass("img-responsive");
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the clear and concise help.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: No prob. :) Could you mark it as the answer, please?